# How to rewrite PNG as a parameter to a PHP script and pass a GET parameter using Mod-Rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a URL to a PNG image, using the PHP logo as an example,

`http://images.punyman.com/uploads/b2360c502732e4f5b3cd.png`,

that I'd like to rewrite to

`http://images.punyman.com/?img=b2360c502732e4f5b3cd`

As well, I'd like to rewrite

`http://images.punyman.com/uploads/b2360c502732e4f5b3cd.png?raw`

to

`http://images.punyman.com/?img=b2360c502732e4f5b3cd&raw`

So far, I've tried the following, which not only doesn't work, I don't know how to how to pass on the `raw` GET parameter

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^uploads/(\w+)\.png$ index.php?img=$1 [L]
```

Comment: There is no `index.php` in any of your URL examples, only in the rule you tried. Please explain.

Comment: index.php is at the root of my URL (`images.punyman.com`), and is just a script that handles the image, (`http://images.punyman.com/`) is the same as (`http://images.punyman.com/index.php`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this instead, in one .htaccess file at root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^uploads/([^.]+)\.png  /index.php?img=$1  [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: I added `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !/uploads/.*\.png` for the script to work properly before the rule, but this works. Thanks :)